# Kafka 10 - Python Client with Authentication and Authorization

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a Kafka10 cluster with SASL_SSL (Authentication( JAAS ) and Authorization) enabled.
  Able to connect thru SASL using the Java client with the below props.

```
ssl.keystore.location="client_keystore.jks"
ssl.keystore.password="password"
ssl.truststore.location="clienttruststore"
ssl.truststore.password="password"
```

and passing the JAAS conf file thru the JVM params.

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/client_jaas.conf
```

Is there anyway to achieve the same thing with the python client?

Comment: So what was the solution? In the solution beloew, there is username/password... no usage of keystore anymore?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been connecting to IBM Message Hub which is kafka under the hood using code like this:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
import ssl

sasl_mechanism = 'PLAIN'
security_protocol = 'SASL_SSL'

# Create a new context using system defaults, disable all but TLS1.2
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = app.config['KAFKA_BROKERS_SASL'],
                         sasl_plain_username = app.config['KAFKA_USERNAME'],
                         sasl_plain_password = app.config['KAFKA_PASSWORD'],
                         security_protocol = security_protocol,
                         ssl_context = context,
                         sasl_mechanism = sasl_mechanism,
                         api_version = (0,10),
                         retries=5)

def send_message(message):

    try:
        producer.send(app.config['KAFKA_TOPIC'], message.encode('utf-8'))
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
```

Answer (score 3):

Below are the configurations that worked for me for SASL_SSL using kafka-python client. I am using kafka-python 1.4.6 with kafka 2.2.0 on CentOS 6.
These configurations can be used for PLAINTEXT and SSL security protocols along with SASL_SSL and SASL_PLAINTEXT.

Bash script to generate key files, CARoot, and self-signed cert for use with SSL:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Step 1
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -validity 365 -keyalg RSA -genkey
#Step 2
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout ca-key -out ca-cert -days 365
keytool -keystore server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert
keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert
#Step 3
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -certreq -file cert-file
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert -CAkey ca-key -in cert-file -out cert-signed -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:admin123
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias localhost -import -file cert-signed
```

You can then use the following command to extract the CARoot.pem:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias CARoot -keystore server.keystore.jks -rfc -file CARoot.pem
```

In my server.properties file I have:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9091,SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093,SASL_SSL://localhost:9094
security.protocol=SSL
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=admin123
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=admin123
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9091,SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093,SASL_SSL://localhost:9094
```

In my JAAS configuration file(/etc/kafka/kafka_plain_jaas.conf):

```
KafkaServer {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username=kafka
   password=kafka-secret
   user_username=password;
};
KafkaClient {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username=username
  password=password;
};
```

Before starting the Kafka server, need to run the following:

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_plain_jaas.conf"
```

Python consumer and producer:
The ssl_context and api_version are what caused SSL handshake errors to occur for me, leading to a timeout. So I commented those out. (There were some tutorials out there that mentioned to use those.)

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer
import kafka
import ssl
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

try:
    topic = "sendMessage"
    sasl_mechanism = "PLAIN"
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    security_protocol = "SASL_SSL"

    #context = ssl.create_default_context()
    #context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
    #context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers='localhost:9094',
                              #api_version=(0, 10),
                              security_protocol=security_protocol,
                              #ssl_context=context,
                              ssl_check_hostname=True,
                              ssl_cafile='../keys/CARoot.pem',
                              sasl_mechanism = sasl_mechanism,
                              sasl_plain_username = username,
                              sasl_plain_password = password)
                              #ssl_certfile='../keys/certificate.pem',
                              #ssl_keyfile='../keys/key.pem')#,api_version = (0, 10))

    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9094',
                             #api_version=(0, 10),
                             security_protocol=security_protocol,
                             #ssl_context=context,
                             ssl_check_hostname=True,
                             ssl_cafile='../keys/CARoot.pem',
                             sasl_mechanism=sasl_mechanism,
                             sasl_plain_username=username,
                             sasl_plain_password=password)
                              #ssl_certfile='../keys/certificate.pem',
                              #ssl_keyfile='../keys/key.pem')#, api_version = (0,10))
    # Write hello world to test topic
    producer.send(topic, bytes("Hello World SSL"))
    producer.flush()


    for msg in consumer:
        print(msg)


except Exception as e:
    print e
```